# drop down list not working in bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

```
<li class="dropdown">
<a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Page 1
<span class="caret"></span></a>
<ul class="dropdown-menu">
  <li><a href="#">Page 1-1</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Page 1-2</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Page 1-3</a></li>
</ul>
```

i am trying to create a drop down list but the drop down does not appear when clicked

Comment: Have you included the bootstrap JavaScript?

Comment: Your code works fine... you're definitely missing the bootstrap.js from your solution or you've not included a reference to it in your page.

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">

  <div class="dropdown">
    <button class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">Name Of Dropdown
    <span class="caret"></span></button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li><a href="#">Page 1-1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Page 1-2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Page 1-3</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```